# PHP class attribute type hint

Tags: php

I just figured out that PHP5 supports [type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) for function arguments. Is it possible to use this type hinting for class attributes like this:

```
private FooClass $fo;
```

Or even for creating new object like this inside function:

```
FooClass $ff = new FooClass();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible to enforce attribute type like that. But if you'll use decent IDE like PHPStorm you can make a type hint in PHPDoc comment like:

```
class Foo
    {
    /**
     * @var Bar
     */
    private $barObject;
    }
```

Then it will check and warn you when you attempt to assign or modify its value with wrong type.

As for enforcing variable type - PHP is a loosely typed language, so no, it's not possible. Again, with decent IDE you can help yourself with PHPDoc comment:

```
/**
 * @var $bar Bar
 */
$bar = somethingThatReturnsBar();
```

but that's all.

Answer (score 2):

You can ensure a functions argument is an instance of a specific class using the following code...

```
$fo = new FooClass();

function myFunction (FooClass $fo){
    // Your Code Here
}
```

If the $fo argument was not an instance of the FooClass an error would be triggered.

Answer (score 2):

No, although if you feel you really need that you can look at Hack (http://hacklang.org/).

You can, however, control the setting of your private variables by using type hinting in arguments:

```
class MyClass {
    private $foo;

    public function setFoo(FooClass $foo) {
        $this->foo = $foo;
    }
}
```